# Неравенство строк, telebot

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Использую библиотеку telebot.Есть код, который при вводе текста(не команды!) считывает его и разделяет по-строчно.

```
words = text.split("\n")
```

После чего, строки в файле сравниваются с строками в списке.

```
f = open('fun.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
    if line not in words and len(line) > 2:
        final_string += line + "\n"
```

И в final_string записываются строки, которых нет в массиве.
После введения текста телеграмм боту и сравнивая его с файловым, ни одна строка не совпадает, и весь текст который я прислал записывается в финальную строку, хотя текст который я прислал совпадает.
К примеру в файле записан текст stackoverflow(без пробелов и тд.). Пишу боту, stackoverflow.

Результат, если использовать `line in string это False`.
Вот так я ввожу текст:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выводится False.

**С чем это может быть связано, если я уже даже конвертировал строку с помощью** `str()` **?** **Как решить эту проблему?**

P.S.Скорее всего, проблема со считиванием информации с файла,т.к. если сравнить `line` с `stackoverflow`, а в файле этот текст есть, всегда возвращает `False`. А если сравнить `"stackoverflow" in string` то выводит `True`, хотя вроде всё правильно.

Текстовый файл:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S.S.Напишите, пожалуйста, если понадобится более подробная информация, и какая.

Comment: А что находится в `line`, а что в `string`? Покажите вывод: `print('{} vs {}'.format(repr(line), repr(string)))`. Кст, правильнее проверять не `not (line in string)`, а `line not in string`. А так у вас скорее всего в `line` = `"stackoverflow\n"`, а в `string = "stackoverflow"`, что ожидаемо при `line in string` возвращает `False`, а `string in line` -- `True`

Comment: @gil9red String - список в котором содержатся каждая строки текста который я отправляю боту.Выводит: 'stackoverflow\n' vs ['delete', 'stackoverflow'], понял свою ошибку, а ответ ниже подсказал функцию которую нужно использовать.Спасибо!

Comment: `string` вводит в заблуждение. Переименуйте лучше в `words` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, когда вы делаете

```
for line in f:
```

то из файла строка считывается вместе с символом перевода строки в конце.

Поэтому прежде чем дальше работать со строкой, вам нужно очистить её от служебных символов:

```
for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    # И уже теперь сравнивайте строку с чем нужно
```

Comment: Там кроме `\n` может и `\r` находиться, так что `strip` явно будет нужным, хотя автору хватило бы и `rstrip` :)